# Is it okay to change a source code I haven't written?

Tags: python, kivy

I only started coding a couple months ago and I'm developing an App with Python and KivyMD.

There is a StringProperty in one of KivyMD's classes that I want to change and only managed to do it by changing the source code.

So I wondered how the community sees this. I mean, when I get a job and I see myself in this situation, it would be okay to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is this about contributing to an open source project, changing code written by colleagues, or changing code in your local copy of an open source library? I assume it's the latter. In this case: No one will stop you, but remember that your code will then not work when executed on any other system or when you update your KivyMD installation.

Comment: @tobias_k It's changing code in my local copy of an open source library! Now that you said it like this, I feel like it's okay to do it, right?

Comment: Sometimes that's what you have to do... but what happens when the library updates? This leads to huge headaches.

Comment: @tobias_k I will be aware of the possibility of the code not working in other updates! But I think as I'm using a venv it won't ruin other projects. Thanks man!

Comment: @JETM I think because I'm using a venv that won't bring me much trouble on updates, right?

Comment: You could also monkey patch the class in question from within your own code (or use a wrapper class) instead of touching the upstream project.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Never heard of that term, but I just researched and it seems very fittable. Thanks!!

Comment: @LuizFernandoSilveira I think it would benefit you to post a fuller example of what you're trying to achieve. Modifying the local source code of a library is going to cause you headaches down the line and there is almost certainly an easier way to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork the repo, make your changes and use changed code in your project. As stated:

> If you wish to contribute, [the project's coding style](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wikis/Coding-style) is available there as well.

So, try to follow that code style and create a pull request afterward. If that PR is accepted, then you don't need to use your repo for your project in the future, just the original.

Comment: This suggestion is good practice when dealing with open source code, if you see the change you're making as beneficial to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

> when I get a job and I see myself in this situation, it would be okay to do it?

Almost certainly not. The reason being: modifying the source code on your local machine is no use to anyone but yourself. In a work environment, everyone is going to need those changes (unless you're just debugging) and asking your colleagues to copy and paste your custom library file around would quickly turn into a nightmare.

Your question really needs the example of what you're trying to achieve because I'd be surprised if KivyMD has been written in a way that means you can't just sub-class the class you want to change and change the StringProperty that way.

It may well be that you want to do something that cannot be achieved without modifying the source like you say, at which point your will have to fork the repository and add your changes to it.